# sed - simple regular expression replacement not replacing

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to use sed to remove any subdomain prefix from a list of hostnames, but it's not replacing anything when I use a regular expression.  Here's the simplified example that's not working:

```
echo "subdomainxyz.example.com" | sed 's/[a-z]+\.example\.com//'
```

When I hard-code a particular subdomain in there, it works just fine:

```
echo "subdomainxyz.example.com" | sed 's/subdomainxyz\.example.com/example.com/'
```

Comment: @Gilles My feelings wouldn't be hurt if you decide to close this as already answered; however, because the question is posed differently, I'm a fan of keeping it open because people may be more apt to find the solution if they are searching something similar.  IMO anything within reason that increases the chances that a SE result comes up in the search engines is a benefit to the community.

Comment: That's exactly why we don't delete duplicates: they will keep coming up in search engines.

Comment: But this question doesn’t make a good signpost.  It’s *about* finding, matching, and searching — and it doesn’t mention any of those key words.  I wonder whether somebody else who has this problem is really likely to Google for “replacement” or “replacing”.  P.S. It might be useful to edit the canonical question to include a gratuitous mention of the word “search” simply to make it easier to locate.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer before I submitted the question but since I had typed it up already, I thought I'd post it in case it's helpful for anyone.

The key thing that was needed was to add the `-r` flag (may be `-E` on some versions) to tell `sed` to support extended regular expressions which is needed to use the character class / range syntax and the plus operator `[a-z]+`.  This is just like you have to do with `grep` (for some reason I thought `sed` defaulted to extended regular expressions but that was incorrect).

Here's a working example:

```
echo "subdomainxyz.example.com" | sed -r 's/[a-z]+\.example\.com/example.com/'
```

EDIT (credit steeldriver):

Simply escaping the plus sign works without -r being required.  Example:

```
echo "subdomainxyz.example.com" | sed 's/[a-z]\+\.example\.com/example.com/'
```

Comment: AFAIK the only part of your expression that is not supported by the basic regular expression (BRE) syntax is the `+` operator: you could have used `\+` or (POSIXly) `\{1,\}` to mean one-or-more of the preceding RE without the `-r` or `-E` switch.

Comment: @steeldriver You're right `\+` did the trick without `-r` being required.  I'll edit my answer.